# Script to install app in iOS Simulator

Tags: shell, command-line, ios-simulator

I am trying to automate the process of building an app, running unit tests, and finally running UI tests.

I am building the app via command line (xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator6.0) in some directory.

How do I install this app to the iOS simulator via command line (in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator//Applications)?

I tried:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication MyApp.app/MyApp
```

but this opens a new finder window named "iOS Simulator could not find the application to simulate".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I made a shell script which installs the app to the simulator.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Pick a uuid for the app (or reuse existing one).
if ! [ -f installApp.uuid ]; then
    uuidgen > installApp.uuid
fi
UUID=$(cat installApp.uuid)
#create supporting folders
TOPDIR="$HOME/Library/Application Support/\
iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/$UUID/"
mkdir -p "$TOPDIR"
mkdir -p "$TOPDIR/Documents"
mkdir -p "$TOPDIR/Library"
mkdir -p "$TOPDIR/tmp"
mkdir -p "$TOPDIR/$1.app"

#copy all the app file to the simulators directory
cp -r * "$TOPDIR/$1.app"
```

How to use this script to install the app:

1. Change this line:

   ```
   TOPDIR="$HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/$UUID/"
   ```

   to reflect the version of iPhone Simulator you are using i.e. `6.0`/`7.1`.
2. Save the script as `installApp.sh` in your `project_name.app/` folder.
3. Open a terminal window and run `installApp` from the project directory.

   - So if I have my `project_name.app/` with a project inside. Type in the terminal:

   > cd path/to/project_name.app/
4. Then `./installApp` to install the app to the simulator.

I got the idea from Jeffrey Scofield: [Run iOS Simulator from the Command Line](http://psellos.com/2012/05/2012.05.iossim-command-line-2.html)

---

For **iOS8 and the new XCode** Apple changed a few things and made it difficult to install apps via the command line. It is still possible to do:

1. First you need to find the app directory (assuming you have installed apps): `find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices -name '*.app'`
2. This will list all the paths that have a custom app installed. E.g.

`/34792D41-55A9-40F5-AAC5-16F742F1F3E4/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BA2A285-6902-45A8-9445-FC3E46601F51/YourApp.app`

3. There will be multiple UUID parent directories with the structure above. Each UUID corresponds to a simulator for a different device. Open the top directory and you will find a `device.plist` file. This file will contain the device it is simulating:

> ```
> <dict>
>     ...
>     <string>34792D41-55A9-40F5-AAC5-16F742F1F3E4</string>
>     <string>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus</string>
>     ...
> </dict>
> ```

4. If you want to install your app for iPhone-6-Plus this is the directory you would do it in. Run the shell script above to install the app. Change the `TOPDIR` path to `$HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{UUID for device}/data/Containers/Bundle/Applications/$UUID/`

Comment: Sadly, this does not seem to work any longer (I'm using iOS 7.1)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. The directory is still there, the files are copied, but the simulator does not show the app on the springboard.

Comment: @thomers it does work with iOS 7.1, you just have to put this script into the `project_name.app` folder and rename `6.0` to `7.1` (but it often crashes). Then you run `installApp` from that directory. So if I have my `project.app/` with a `project` inside. I would `cd project.app/` and run `./installApp project`. I'm also leaving this comment as better documentation for future readers.

Comment: @stackErr it's the app, the script works great. I realized that I made a mistake, because I extracted my app out of an `.ipa` Payload, and that will always crash, because it's compiled for the iPhone arm architecture, and not x86 iPhone Simulator.

Comment: With iOS8, it looks difficult.

Comment: @Vijay it is difficult but possible. Added iOS8 instructions.

Answer (score 20):

As of Xcode 6, you should be able to use `simctl` to accomplish this.

1) Get the list of available devices:

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

1a) Assuming you have `jq` installed, you can use it to get only those devices that are actually available:

```
xcrun simctl list devices -j \
| jq -rc '.[] | .[] | .[] | select( .availability | contains( "(available)" ) ) '
```

1b) Or even filter further by iPhone or iPad:

```
xcrun simctl list devices -j \
| jq -rc '.[] | .[] | .[] | select( .name | contains( "iPhone" ), contains( "iPad" ) ) | select( .availability | contains( "(available)" ) ) '
```

2) Once you have the UDID of the device you want to install to:

```
xcrun simctl install $DEVICE_UDID /path/to/your/app
```

2a) Or, if you want to just install to the booted device:

```
xcrun simctl install booted /path/to/your/app
```

---

Where this gets really handy is if you want to run the same app on all the devices:

1) Reset / erase all simulators:

```
xcrun simctl erase all
```

2) Open one Simulator instance for each test:

```
open -n /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
(Ignore the 'Booted' error and switch hardware.)
```

3) Get UDIDs of available devices we want to install to:

```
DEVICES=$( xcrun simctl list devices -j | jq -rc '.[] | .[] | .[] | select( .name | contains( "iPhone" ), contains( "iPad" ) ) | select( .availability | contains( "(available)" ) ) | select( .state == "Booted" ) | .udid ' )
```

4) Install the app (which must be built for the appropriate simulator SDK):

```
for device in DEVICES ; do xcrun simctl install $device /path/to/app ; done
```

5) For convenience, launch the app on each device:

```
for device in $DEVICES ; do xcrun simctl launch $device your.product.app.id ; done
```